# Display/Hide an Empty Table On Click of Javascript Checkbox Using Jquery and Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to search anything about automatic rendering of an empty table row for each selected javascript checkbox using jquery and visualforce.

The aim is for every selected row from `CustomObj__c`, there must be an empty `CustomObj2__c` table row displayed.

I am thinking in switching to using jquery for the reason that actionsupport didn't work successfully :( Besides, samples from the internet focus more on the object field with checkbox datatype, instead of javascript-made checkbox.

Here's vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObj__c">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID) {
            var inputCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckbox.length; i++) {
                if(inputCheckbox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1) {
                    inputCheckbox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>  

    <apex:pageBlock id="section1" rendered="{!Section1}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList}" var="c">
            <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'chk')"/>
            </apex:facet>   
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.IsSelected}" id="chk">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="section2"/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Mobile__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable>    
    </apex:pageBlock>  

    <apex:pageBlock id="section2" rendered="{!Section2}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList2}" var="c2">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c2.CellNo__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

***Note:** `cList2` is an empty table row for another custom object named `CustomObj2__c`.

As per the jquery part, I'm still not sure on how to do this with visualforce page.

**Controller:**

```
public class SampleController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public List<CustomObj__c> cList {get;set;}
    public List<CustomObj2__c> cList2 {get;set;}
    public Boolean Section1 {get;set;} 
    public Boolean Section2 {get;set;}

    public SampleController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        controller = con;
        Section1 = true;
    }

    public void controllermethod() {
        List<CustomObj2__c> cList2 = new List<CustomObj2__c>();
        cList2.add(new CustomObj2__c()); 
    }

    //other methods....
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObj__c" extensions="SampleController">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID) {
            var inputCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckbox.length; i++) {
                if(inputCheckbox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1) {
                    inputCheckbox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>  

    <apex:pageBlock id="section1" rendered="{!Section1}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList}" var="c">
            <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'chk')"/>
            </apex:facet>   
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.IsSelected}" id="chk">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="section2" action={!controllermethod}/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Mobile__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable>    
    </apex:pageBlock>  

    <apex:outputPanel id="section2">
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Section2}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList2}" var="c2">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c2.CellNo__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily
When you select the checkbox

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="section2" action="{!controllermethod}" />
```

call controller method and in your controller

```
public void controllermethod()
{
   cList2.add(new CustomObj2__c())
}
```

Also put this code in `apex:outputpanel` and `rerender` that section

```
<apex:outputpanel id="section2" >
      <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Section2}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cList2}" var="c2">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c2.CellNo__c}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

PS: If some one select the checkbox and then deselect and then again select it will add blank line every time you need to handle that case as well.

**Update your code as**

```
public SampleController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        controller = con;
        Section1 = true;
        cList2 = new List<CustomObj2__c>();
    }

    public void controllermethod() {

        cList2.add(new CustomObj2__c()); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your immediate response. By the way, I've done what you've suggested above, but still, empty table row for `CustomObj2__c` doesn't display.

Comment: @eagerlearner make sure you follow all steps and paste your controller code too.

Comment: I've added the controller and the modified vf page based from your suggestion. Those are on the most bottom part of my original post, thanks.

Comment: @eagerlearner remove this line `List<CustomObj2__c> cList2 = new List<CustomObj2__c>();` from your method. check my updated code.

Comment: I removed this part `List<CustomObj2__c> cList2 = new List<CustomObj2__c>()` from the controllermethod()  and followed your updated code. But still, section2 does not appear on checkbox click.  Does it have anything to do with the fact that the checkbox is generated via javascript?

Comment: @eagerlearner I also updated the rerender section check that too.

Comment: I based also the rerender section on your suggestion. Here's the rerender section: `<apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="section2" action="{!controllermethod}" />`

Comment: @eagerlearner check if your controller actually get called. If there is some required fields on UI controller will not get called.

Comment: I've checked the requirements and it turns out I haven't set any required fields.

Comment: still not working, but thanks for all your help.

Comment: @eagerlearner try `apex:actionSupport event="onchange"`

Comment: tried that, but doesn't work also