# How to Avoid Adding Extra Table Row When Enabling Through Checkbox Click Using Jquery and Visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I encounter this weird problem in visualforce page wherein for every checkbox click, there is an extra table row added, whether I tick/untick it. The table row is supposed to display only if I tick the checkbox, and hide if I untick it.

There's nothing wrong with displaying the table row whenever I tick the checkbox. This feature works. The only problem is that every time I untick it, it adds another table row, instead of hiding the said table row.

I use two objects: the standard `Account` object and a custom object named `CustomObj__c`.

**Controller: AccountController**

```
public class AccountController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public Boolean b1 {get;set;}
    public List<Account> accList {get;set;}
    public List<CustomObj__c> customList {get;set;}
    public List<MyWrapper> wrapCls {get;set;}

    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        controller = con;
        b1 = true;       
        wrapCls = new List<MyWrapper>():
        customList = new List<CustomObj__c>();
    }

    public void clickAction() {
        customList.add(new CustomObj__c()); 
    }

    public class MyWrapper {
        public Account listA {get;set;}
        public Boolean IsSelected {get;set;}

        public MyWrapper(Boolean sel, Account a) {
            IsSelected = sel;
            listA = a;
        } 
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page: AccountPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController">

    <style type="text/css">
        #blkToRender {
            display: none;
        } 
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID) {
            var inputCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckbox.length; i++) {
                if(inputCheckbox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1) {
                    inputCheckbox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[id$=chk]').onclick(function() {
                $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','block');
            });
        }); 

    </script>  

    <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" rendered="{!b1}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapCls}" var="acc">
            <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'chk')"/>
            </apex:facet>   
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acc.IsSelected}" id="chk">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="blkToRender" action={!clickAction}/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!acc.listA.Type}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable>    
    </apex:pageBlock>  

    <apex:pageBlockTable id="blkToRender" value="{!customList}" var="cl">
               <apex:column>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!cl.Type__c}"/>
               </apex:column>   
           </apex:pageBlockTable> 

    </apex:pageBlock>   

</apex:page>
```

**Updated Controller:**

```
public class AccountController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public Account returnAcc {get;set;}
    public Boolean b1 {get;set;}
    public List<Account> accList {get;set;}
    public List<CustomObj__c> customList {get;set;}
    public List<MyWrapper> wrapCls {get;set;}

    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        controller = con;
        b1 = true;       
        wrapCls = new List<MyWrapper>():
        customList = new List<CustomObj__c>();
        returnAcc = new Account();
    }

    public void accSearch() {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        List<MyWrapper> wraptemp = new List<MyWrapper>();

        accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, CustomObj__c, Type FROM Account WHERE CustomObj__c =: returnAcc.CustomObj__c];

        for(Account accloop : accounts) {
            wraptemp.add(new MyWrapper(false,accloop));
        }

        if(wraptemp != null) {
            wrapCls = wraptemp;
        }

    }  

    public void clickAction() {
        customList.add(new CustomObj__c()); 
    }

    public class MyWrapper {
        public Account listA {get;set;}
        public Boolean IsSelected {get;set;}

        public MyWrapper(Boolean sel, Account a) {
            IsSelected = sel;
            listA = a;
        } 
    }
}
```

**Updated VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID) {
            var inputCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckbox.length; i++) {
                if(inputCheckbox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1) {
                    inputCheckbox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayTable(obj) {
        if(obj.checked) {
            $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','block');
            CallApexMethod();
        }
        else {
            $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','none');
        }
    }      
    </script>  

    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!clickAction}" rerender="blkToRender" oncomplete="alert(1);"/>

    <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" rendered="{!b1}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!returnAcc.CustomObj__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!accSearch}" event="onchange" />
        </apex:inputField>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapCls}" var="acc">
            <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'chk')"/>
            </apex:facet>   
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acc.IsSelected}" id="chk" onclick="displayTable(this)">
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!acc.listA.Type}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable>    
    </apex:pageBlock>  

    <apex:pageBlockTable id="blkToRender" value="{!customList}" var="cl">
               <apex:column>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!cl.Type__c}"/>
               </apex:column>   
           </apex:pageBlockTable> 

    </apex:pageBlock>   

</apex:page>
```

Comment: I thought we have seen this question several times not sure if it is same user creating multiple users or just the code is being copied frequently lately. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143749/display-hide-an-empty-table-on-click-of-javascript-checkbox-using-jquery-and-vis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is doing this because you have written code like this.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acc.IsSelected}" id="chk">
     <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="blkToRender" action={!clickAction}/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

You are controller method onclick of checkbox and which in turn add the row.

You need to do something like

```
<script>
function displayTable(obj)
{

if(obj.checked)
{
  $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','block');
   //call other method or controller code here
}
else
  $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','none');

}
</script>
 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acc.IsSelected}" id="chk" onclick="displayTable(this)"/>
```

You can call controller method here and also remove the jquery method from your code.

I am not sure that you are still facing this problem because when I run your code in my org after getting some compile time error (most common **apex:form** is missing) the code run successfully for me.

I have changed `customObj` with `Contact` for reproduction.

**Apex Class**

```
public class AccountController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public Account returnAcc {get;set;}
    public Boolean b1 {get;set;}
    public List<Account> accList {get;set;}
    public List<contact> customList {get;set;}
    public List<MyWrapper> wrapCls {get;set;}

    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        controller = con;
        b1 = true;       
        wrapCls = new List<MyWrapper>();
        customList = new List<contact>();
        returnAcc = new Account();
    }

    public void accSearch() {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        List<MyWrapper> wraptemp = new List<MyWrapper>();

        accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Type FROM Account WHERE Name =: returnAcc.Name];

        for(Account accloop : accounts) {
            wraptemp.add(new MyWrapper(false,accloop));
        }

        if(wraptemp != null) {
            wrapCls = wraptemp;
        }

    }  

    public void clickAction() {
        customList.add(new contact()); 
    }

    public class MyWrapper {
        public Account listA {get;set;}
        public Boolean IsSelected {get;set;}

        public MyWrapper(Boolean sel, Account a) {
            IsSelected = sel;
            listA = a;
        } 
    }
}
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController">
    <apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID) {
            var inputCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckbox.length; i++) {
                if(inputCheckbox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1) {
                    inputCheckbox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayTable(obj) {
        if(obj.checked) {
            $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','block');
            CallApexMethod();
        }
        else {
            $('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','none');
        }
    }      
    </script>  

    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!clickAction}" rerender="blkToRender" oncomplete="alert(1);"/>

    <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" rendered="{!b1}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!returnAcc.Name}">
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!accSearch}" event="onchange" />
        </apex:inputField>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapCls}" var="acc">
            <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'chk')"/>
            </apex:facet>   
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!acc.IsSelected}" id="chk" onclick="displayTable(this)"/>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!acc.listA.Type}"/>
            </apex:column>   

        </apex:pageBlockTable>    


         <apex:pageBlockTable id="blkToRender" value="{!customList}" var="cl">
               <apex:column>
                   <apex:inputField value="{!cl.firstName}"/>
               </apex:column>   
           </apex:pageBlockTable> 
       </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Working Screenshot**
[image]
[image: With Alert]
[image]

Comment: should i still include the `actionsupport` line in my vf page?

Comment: @curdual you can remove that as well.if you want to call controller method you can do that using `actionfunction`

Comment: I've tried adding this line at the top of the `<apex:pageBlock>` part: `<apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!clickAction}"/>` and added this below `$('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','block');` `CallApexMethod()`, but the table row does not display anymore.

Comment: @curdual add `rerender=blkToRender` in apex function. And check your action function actually get called.

Comment: I just added `rerender="blkToRender"` inside the actionFunction but it still doesn't work. I don't know how to check if the function actually gets called. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: @curdual add `oncomplete="alert(1);` in your action function and check if you get any alert. Also check if you are getting any exception in console.

Comment: there are no alerts whatsoever, and there aren't any exception in the console.

Comment: @curdual share your updated code. Also from where you are filling wraplist

Comment: Kindly see my updated post. I've added there both the updated controller and vf page. In my updated controller, you can notice that there's a new method `accSearch()`, which is being called in this newly added line in the vf page: `<apex:inputField value="{!returnAcc.CustomObj__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!accSearch}" event="onchange" />
        </apex:inputField>`. I've also made some notifications based on what you have suggested.

Comment: *modifications (instead of notifications)

Comment: @curdual can you confirm`$('[id$=blkToRender]').css('display','block');`is this line actually working and show hide the section

Comment: the table does not display anymore, unlike on my original posted code where I am still using jquery. the hide function does not work also. on my original posted code, the table adds an extra row when I untick the checkbox

Comment: @curdual check my updated answer.

Comment: After thorough code inspection, I've noticed that jquery codes I've used in my original post were commented in `<!-- -->` format, instead of `/*... */`. Deleting all the unnecessary comments and leaving only the javascript function solves the problem behind why the display/hide function is not working. Didn't know simple comment formatting affects the behavior of javascript codes that much. On the other hand, extra row is still added each time I tick/untick the checkbox, where it's supposed to depend the number of empty rows displayed on the number of selected rows only.

Comment: I really do appreciate your efforts in helping. Thanks for having the patience in guiding me, that sure helped me a lot :)